# The tower of ramification indices

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K\subset L\subset M$ be an extension of number fields. Let $R\subset S\subset T$, be their algebraic integers rings, respectively. Suppose that $P\subset R$, $Q\subset S$, $U\subset T$ be a prime ideals such that $U\cap S=Q,Q\cap R=P$.

I need to show that $e(U|P)=e(U|Q)e(Q|P)$. ($e$ is the ramification index)

I am trying to prove it using the unique factorisation.

I know $R,S,$ & $T$ are Dedekind domains. So.

$PT=U^{e(U|P)}{U_2}^{t_2}...{U_r}^{t_r}$

$PS=Q^{e(Q|P)}{N_2}^{s_2}...{N_k}^{s_i}$

$QT=U^{e(U|Q)}{F_2}^{x_2}...{F_b}^{x_j}$

All the ideals in the factorisation are prime ideals.

how to write $PT=U^{({{e(U|Q)}})^{e(Q|P)}}.....$ and we deduce the result for the unique factorisation.

Comment: Does $(PS)T=PT$? I showed using set theoretic . $1\in S$. So, the result will be easy.. Am I right ??

Comment: Yes, extension of ideals is transitive.